# How to install audio drivers for Acer Revo nettop?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, audio, acer-revo

I have a Acer Revo nettop.  I wiped the XP Home install that came on the machine and put XP Pro on.

Acer's support website would lead you to believe that this product does not exist.  I know it has a NVIDIA ION LE chipset so I headed over to nvidia.com to download drivers.  Ive downloaded and installed the Chipset drivers, Graphics Drivers, and HDMI audio drivers.

I have no sound.  Under Device Manager there is an unknown Audio Device on High Definition Audio Bus.  I do not have an HDMI cable to test hdmi audio.  I would just like the standard audio mini-jack output to work.

Anyone know of the correct driver or a generic driver that would work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a guide to [looking up hardware based on it's device ID.](http://www.instantfundas.com/2008/06/how-to-find-drivers-for-unknown-devices.html)

To summarize:

1. In Device Manager, right click your unknown device, and select Properties.
2. Go to the "Details" tab.
3. With "Device Instance Id" selected, you'll see a string such as the one listed below.
4. Use [PCI Database](http://www.pcidatabase.com/) to lookup what device this corresponds to.

```
HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_8384&DEV_7690&SUBSYS_102801C0&REV_1022\4&2DC3B72F&0&0001
```

- VEN_8384 indicates my Vendor ID is 8384.
- DEV_7690 indicates my Device ID is 7690.

In the example, which is my sound card (or codec so it says), searching the Device ID returns: SigmaTel 9200 HD Audio CODEC. Device Manager lists this as SigmaTel High Definition Audio CODEC, so i'd say this is pretty accurate.

From that point, its a matter of finding the drivers for your particular device on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [official nvidia website](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) for all your drivers. There is also a tool you can download which will scan your machine and see what needs to be updated.